# Button not working?

Tags: javascript

So I have this function in javascript -

```
 $(function sort()
```

and html

```
  <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="sort()" />
```

and its not working, another function with a button is working but that doesnt have the $, so is there a different syntax maybe when the $ sign in included?

thanks for replies

Comment: What errors is the JavaScript console giving you?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a function. Try this:

```
 function sort() {
       alert('sort called');
  }
```

The $ is likely part of a framework, probably [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). If you need it in a DOM ready wrapper, you could do this:

```
$(function(){ 
    function sort() {
        alert('sort called');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UHjSs/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in basic JavaScript you usually want to specify a function like this:

```
function sort() {
    // sort algorithm
}
```

`$(function sort()` most probably came from a JavaScript library or framework. Copy/pasting from those files is rather tricky unless you have ample knowledge of JavaScript.